# Redirecting after Success on Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

According to the symfony 2 documentation, by default if a user tries to access a secure page they will be prompt to the login page, after a successful login they will be redirected to the original page they intend to. ([Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success)).

But in my application the user is always been redirected to the / no matter if they try to access mysite.com/blog/post/2/edit.

This is my security.yml:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        main:
            entity: {class: Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\User, property: username}

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 3600
                path: /
                domain: ~
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/signup, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/verification, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/popup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ajax/track, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ajax/socialbox, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    encoders:
        Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:   md5
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false
```

And the login form:

```
<?php $view -> extend('DonePunctisBundle:TemplateBases:default.html.php'); ?>

<?php $view['slots']->start('body')
?>
    <h1 class="worldH1">
                Effettua il <span>login</span> su Punctis<br>e inizia a guadagnare!
         </h1>
         <div id="loginContent" class="container pageContent">
             <?php 
             if(isset($error)){
                 ?>
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <?=$error->getMessage() ?>
                </div>
                 <?php
             } else{?>
             <div class="alert">
                <strong>SEI NUOVO?</strong> Se non hai ancora un account, <a href="#">registrati</a> in meno di un minuto!
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div id="loginForm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h2>Logina via Social</h2>
                         <p>
                            <a href="#" id="signupFacebookStart" class="socialButton">  <?=$this -> get('translator') -> trans('login.via.facebook', array(), 'front'); ?></a>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <a href="#" id="signupTwitterStart" class="socialButton tw">  <?=$this -> get('translator') -> trans('login.via.twitter', array(), 'front'); ?></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">

                        <div id="loginFormCanvas">
                            <h2>Logina via Mail</h2>
                        <form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('done_punctis_user_login_check') ?>" method="post">


                                             <label class="control-label required" for="login_email">Mail:</label>


                                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($last_username)? $last_username: null); ?>"  id="login_email" name="_username" class="input-large">







                                            <label class="control-label required"  for="login_email">Password:</label>

                                                <input type="password"  name="_password" value=""  id="login_email"  class="input-large">




        <label for="remember_me" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked /> Remember me</label>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/" />
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button> <a id="loginForgetPass" href="#">Password Dimenticata?</a>

                                        </form>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

         </div>



<?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the form login strategy for the **property path** is, when a user tries to access a secured page without being authenticated, to store the path into the session before redirecting to the login page. So after successfully logging in, the user is redirected to this path. But are two ways of disabling this mechanism.

If you set the **always_use_default_target_path** option to *TRUE*, no path will be stored and the user will always be redirected to the configured **default_target_path** (default */*) after successfully loggin in.

And if you add a **_target_path** parameter to your request, the user will be redirected to the path this parameter contains after successfully logging in.

So in your example, the user is always redirected to the path **/** after logging in because you  have a **_target_path** hidden field with the value **/** in your login form.

Answer (score 0):

In the `form_login` part of your firewell in **security.yml**, you have to specify that you wanna use *referer* :

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        main:
            entity: {class: Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\User, property: username}

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 3600
                path: /
                domain: ~
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                use_referer: true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/signup, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/verification, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/popup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ajax/track, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ajax/socialbox, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    encoders:
        Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:   md5
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false
```